# GitHub GraphQL API v4 vs REST API v3

Tags: api, github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

Is it possible to list all github's organizations with [GitHub GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) like we did with [REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-all-organizations) ?

Follow a limited sample call :

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/organizations?since=32358551
[
  {
    "login": "NxtReader",
    "id": 32358576,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/NxtReader",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/NxtReader/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/NxtReader/events",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/NxtReader/hooks",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/NxtReader/issues",
    "members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/NxtReader/members{/member}",
    "public_members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/NxtReader/public_members{/member}",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/32358576?v=4",
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "login": "fokkmandag",
    "id": 32358602,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fokkmandag",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fokkmandag/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fokkmandag/events",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fokkmandag/hooks",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fokkmandag/issues",
    "members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fokkmandag/members{/member}",
    "public_members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/fokkmandag/public_members{/member}",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/32358602?v=4",
    "description": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a search query with `type:org` as [`SearchResultItem`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/union/searchresultitem/) can hold an [`Organization`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/organization/) object :

```
{
  search(first: 100, type: USER, query: "type:org") {
    userCount
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      endCursor
    }
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Organization {
          login
          name
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the pagination, you can get the next request with `after` param as the last `endCursor` value if `hasNextPage` is `true`, like :

```
search(after: "Y3Vyc29yOjEwMA==", first: 100, type: USER, query: "type:org")
```